# Load on a server running ActiveMQ increases a lot

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue

We have a ActiveMQ 5.15.10 setup in on of the servers of 5GB RAM machine, 4GB allocated for ActiveMQ. [The default ActiveMQ configuration](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/assembly/src/release/conf/activemq.xml) is used. There are around 140 queues and 3 consumers averagely for every queue, at some queues it may peak upto 7-8 consumers. The recent CPU load on the server is greater than 90%.

What can be the potential reasons for a problem like this? 
And how should we approach to identifying the reasons for this problem?

Any tips would be of great help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying with independent server or java embedded?

Comment: @rns Independent server, 5gb Ram with 2 cores.

Comment: Try to get thread dump when the utilization of CPU is very high and analyse it. In my case, we were having thread leaks causing high memory consumption.

Comment: Also, go to "Tunning the VM" in below link and try with GC parameters,

https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.1.0/perf-tuning.html

Comment: @rns could please elaborate on why the thread leaks were happening in your case? Also I've come across Garbage Collection related to CPU used, any idea on this?

Comment: I was trying with embedded version of ActiveMQ in spring boot. The library which I was using was causing thread issues. After updating the version of activemq it was solved.

Comment: @JustinBertram I'm using ActiveMQ 5.15.10. I will check the GC logs and thread dumps, still need to do that, will get back soon. Thanks.